# Typing in python and understanding by the editor in the of statement

Tags: python

Hi I’m writing a server app with flask and I have a question about the typing,

Let’s say I have this

```
if x is Y:
```

Then the Editor(Vscode) knows that `x` is type of class `Y`

does this feature exist in python

Like in dart

```
if( typeof(x) == Y)
```

then the editor will know the type of `x` in that if statement

Comment: Depends on your code and your IDE.

Comment: `if x is Y:` says nothing about classes. If it's true it means that `x` and `Y` refer to the same object.

Comment: Most editors don't go to that much syntactical analysis.  Now, if you used type hints to declare `x : Y`, then the fancy editors will use that info.

Comment: @TimRoberts Some IDEs like PyCharm do pretty sophisticated analysis, although type hints help greatly.

Comment: In Python you write either `if type(x) == Y:` or `if isinstance(x, Y)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `isinstance(object,class)`

`is` in python checks whether 2 variables point to the same object in memory.